# Spring / Hibernate: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException / org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee

Всем здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь подключить к проекту `Hibernate` через `Spring`, выдаёт исключение. Прошу помощи.

`Hibernate` работает с двумя таблицами, `meals` и `users`. Соответственно, они мапятся к классам `Meals` и `Users`.

При попытке обратиться к этим БД вылетает `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` / `org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException`.

spring-db.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Change DB by comment/uncomment property-placeholder -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/postgres.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
    <!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/hsqldb.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>-->

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.javawebinar.**.repository.jpa"/>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${database.init}">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
        <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:db/populateDB.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <!--no pooling-->
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
          p:packagesToScan="ru.javawebinar.**.model">
        <!--p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnit">-->

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).FORMAT_SQL}" value="${hibernate.format_sql}"/>
                <entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).USE_SQL_COMMENTS}" value="${hibernate.use_sql_comments}"/>
                <!--<entry key="#{T(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings).HBM2DDL_AUTO}" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}"/>-->
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                  p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

</beans>
```

Meal.java:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = Meal.DELETE, query = "DELETE FROM Meal m WHERE m.id=:id"),
//        @NamedQuery(name = Meal.BY_EMAIL, query = "SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.email=?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = User.ALL_SORTED, query = "SELECT m FROM Meal m ORDER BY m.dateTime"),
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "meals")
public class Meal extends BaseEntity {

    public static final String DELETE = "Meal.delete";
    public static final String ALL_SORTED = "Meal.getAllSorted";

    @Column(name = "date_time", columnDefinition = "timestamp default now()")
    @NotBlank
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @Length(max = 40)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "calories")
    @NotNull
    @Range(min = 10, max = 10000)
    private int calories;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    public Meal() {
    }

    public Meal(LocalDateTime dateTime, String description, int calories) {
        this(null, dateTime, description, calories);
    }

    public Meal(Integer id, LocalDateTime dateTime, String description, int calories) {
        super(id);
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.description = description;
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return dateTime.toLocalDate();
    }

    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return dateTime.toLocalTime();
    }

    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setCalories(int calories) {
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Meal{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", dateTime=" + dateTime +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", calories=" + calories +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User.java:

```
package ru.javawebinar.topjava.model;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static ru.javawebinar.topjava.util.MealsUtil.DEFAULT_CALORIES_PER_DAY;

@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = User.DELETE, query = "DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.id=:id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = User.BY_EMAIL, query = "SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles WHERE u.email=?1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = User.ALL_SORTED, query = "SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles ORDER BY u.name, u.email"),
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email", name = "users_unique_email_idx")})
public class User extends NamedEntity {

    public static final String DELETE = "User.delete";
    public static final String BY_EMAIL = "User.getByEmail";
    public static final String ALL_SORTED = "User.getAllSorted";

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Email
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    @Length(min = 5)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bool default true")
    private boolean enabled = true;

    @Column(name = "registered", columnDefinition = "timestamp default now()")
    @NotNull
    private Date registered = new Date();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "role")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Column(name = "calories_per_day", columnDefinition = "int default 2000")
    @Range(min = 10, max = 10000)
    private int caloriesPerDay = DEFAULT_CALORIES_PER_DAY;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User u) {
        this(u.getId(), u.getName(), u.getEmail(), u.getPassword(), u.getCaloriesPerDay(), u.isEnabled(), u.getRoles());
    }

    public User(Integer id, String name, String email, String password, Role role, Role... roles) {
        this(id, name, email, password, DEFAULT_CALORIES_PER_DAY, true, EnumSet.of(role, roles));
    }

    public User(Integer id, String name, String email, String password, int caloriesPerDay, boolean enabled, Set<Role> roles) {
        super(id, name);
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.caloriesPerDay = caloriesPerDay;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    public void setRegistered(Date registered) {
        this.registered = registered;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public int getCaloriesPerDay() {
        return caloriesPerDay;
    }

    public void setCaloriesPerDay(int caloriesPerDay) {
        this.caloriesPerDay = caloriesPerDay;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", email=" + email +
                ", name=" + name +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                ", caloriesPerDay=" + caloriesPerDay +
                '}';
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
11-Aug-2017 17:57:46.341 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate query mapping User.getAllSorted
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at ru.javawebinar.topjava.web.MealServlet.init(MealServlet.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate query mapping User.getAllSorted
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.checkQueryName(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.applyNamedQuery(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:515)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addNamedQuery(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.bindQuery(QueryBinder.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.bindQueries(QueryBinder.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindQueries(AnnotationBinder.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: У вас на сущность `Meal` навешано `@NamedQuery(name = User.ALL_SORTED, query = ..)` вместо `Meal.ALL_SORTED`.

Comment: Спасибо! Выделите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий в отдельный ответ, чтобы я мог его принять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Sergey Gornostaev за наводку: действительно, просто перепутал имя запроса. В сущности Meal у меня было `@NamedQuery(name = User.ALL_SORTED, query = ..)`